# LAMP and PhpMyadmin Powered by Intuz - Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, lamp

I created and EC2 instance of (LAMP and PhpMyadmin Powered by Intuz). I checked the System log and cannot find  the password for phpmyadmin. Can anyone please tell me how to get access to the phpmyadmin password for the EC2 instance. And can you please tell me wether the credentials for the MySQL database and PhpMyAdmin would be the same.

Answer (score 2):

We have identified your issue for that you don't access the phpmyadmin application.

So if you are using the older version like 2.4.18 then you can access the phpmyadmin http://ip-add/phpmyadmin root as username & root as your password or else if you are using the newer version like 2.4.18. then you can access the phpmyadmin http://ip-add/phpmyadmin root as username & intstance-id(i.e- i.0xxxxxxxx) as your password.

You can see your instance id in description section.

For further assist please let us know.